# django unable to load admin css file

Tags: python, django, apache, web-services, amazon-web-services

I'm using Apache to host my main website, and having a django project set aside with it.

1.Apache `proxypass` was configured to listen to 8001 port, as long as `proxypassReverse`

2. in the django project `settings.py`, `django.contrib.staticfiles` is added to `INSTALLED_APPS`
3. STATIC_ROOT is set to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`,  where the BASE_DIR is the absolute path of my project
4. `STATIC_URL is set to '/static/'`
5. operation `python manage.py collectstatic` is already performed and a file named "static" is in my project folder

the page that can't get css files is [www.whiletrue.cc/paradox/admin](https://www.whiletrue.cc/paradox/admin/login/?next=/paradox/admin/)

and here is my apache httpd.conf setting:

```
ProxyPass /paradox http://localhost:8001/paradox

ProxyPassReverse /paradox  http://localhost:8001/paradox

Alias "/static/" "/home/paradox/JS_django/Entry/static"
```

Comment: Post your Apache configuration please. Did you configure `Alias`es for static content?

Comment: no I did not, I think that might be the problem, but why, why deos Apache has to know where my django project's static file located?

Comment: Because it is not recommended to let Django serve the static assets in production environments. You should let Apache serve the static assets without passing them through Django.